# Storing Variable Length Lists in an Array or Table, Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for suggestions on how to store variable length lists in a table.

I am working on an optimization program and I am trying to setup a table with all of my possible permutations.

I have a table with items 1 - 9 with a column for width.

The width of each item can have one or more different discrete values.

For example:

```
1.Width = [100, 125, 150]
2.Width = [100]
3.Width = [100, 125]
```

When I try to add a list to a cell in a pandas table:

```
table.loc[1,'Width'] = [100, 125, 150]
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Clarified.  I want to know how to store a variable length list in a table I can reference.  For example I want to call out item 1, width and receive the list of possible widths.

Comment: How are you defining your `df`? `df = pd.DataFrame()` and `df["width"] = [ [100,125,150], [100,125] ]` seems to work just fine.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])` and 
`df.loc[1, 'Width'] = [100, 125, 150]`
yields:
_ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence._

In your example you are not tying the width values to an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Pandas expects the `Width` column to be `float64`. To be able to put sequences in that column you have to force it to be `object`:

```
df['Width'] = object
df.loc[1, 'Width'] = [100, 200]
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  `df = pd.DataFrame(index = List, columns = ['width'], dtype = object)`

Answer (score 0):

I can do this with a dictionary, but I have not figured out how to do it within a pandas table.

```
w = {}
w[1] = [100, 125, 150]
w[2] = [100, 125]
```